# Python OpenCV 3.x use threshold in LBHP algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, threshold

I wrote a Face detection script with the LBPH algorithm (in Python) `cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`.
My problem is any other person that the algorithm is not trained on, returns me my number. (If it is me it returns 1 but if it's an other person it does the same). So I want to know what I can do, I read something about threshold but I don`t know how to use it and I read about a bug [Link to bug](http://answers.opencv.org/question/82294/cant-get-predict-confidence/). But I don't know how to rebuild the stuff. So I want to know what you recommend me, threshold or rebuilding, or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had a wrong indentation in my code. I returned the number for training with the python `return` command and so it stoped looping and only trained one number and image.